# How do I solve this Open AI gym installation problem?

Tags: python, pip, conda, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym
    cd gym
    pip install -e .
```

When I follow the documentation for installation it throws this error:

```
Failed to build box2d-py mujoco-py
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, mujoco-py which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: box2d-py, glfw, Cython, imageio, lockfile, mujoco-py, gym
    Running setup.py install for box2d-py ... error
```

I have seen others having the same issues however they suggested that I must uninstall python 2.7 and use only python 3.
I have checked my python version and it is only 3.7 and no other versions are available so can someone help me out.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\m\.conda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MITHIL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\m1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gruiq9b6'
       cwd: C:\Users\M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\box2d-py\
  Complete output (16 lines):
  Using setuptools (version 49.6.0.post20200814).
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
  copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
  running build_ext
  building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
  swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
  swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
  Running setup.py clean for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
Installing collected packages: box2d-py
    Running setup.py install for box2d-py ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\m\.conda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\M~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\M~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-67o7g705\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\m\.conda\envs\tensorflow\Include\box2d-py'
         cwd: C:\Users\M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\box2d-py\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 49.6.0.post20200814).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\m\.conda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MITHIL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\M~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ozh5a9c\\box2d-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-67o7g705\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\m\.conda\envs\tensorflow\Include\box2d-py' 
Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: did you check also `pip -V` ? Did you try to install directly from server with `pip install gym`? What system do you use - Windows, Linux, Mac? It seems Windows support is experimental. Some elements need to install C/C++ libraries.

Comment: Please provide the complete error log.

Comment: @hoefling I have added the error log.

Comment: You need to install Swig.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
pip install gym==0.7.4
```

This is a lite version.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to run the following:

```
$ apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libosmesa6-dev xvfb ffmpeg curl patchelf libglfw3 libglfw3-dev cmake zlib1g zlib1g-dev swig
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution for very similar problem

I had very similar problem with instalation `Box2` as `tensorflow` docs stated

`pip install gym[Box2D]`

###### Error log was pretty similar

```
    Complete output (18 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 61.2.0).
    running install
    C:\Users\Greg\anaconda3\envs\driver\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
```

but I have found very simple solution:

`pip install Box2D`

Newest modules that work for me:

- Box2D==2.3.10
- gym==0.24.0